# Displaying a device which has changed it's connection ID in the last week using Arcade Expression in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, expression, arcade

I have about 250 devices in a map, but I want to only display devices that have had a certain attribute change within the past week.

I have minimal experience with Arcade expressions and cannot find guidance for this particular query online.

Comment: Does the data contain a field that records when the attribute is changed?

Comment: It does not. It's possible that this could be added

Answer (score 0):

If you had a field containing the date the attribute was changed ("DateField"), you could use something like this

```
var days = DateDiff(Date($feature.DateField), Now(), 'days');
if (days <= 7) {
  return "Changed last week";
}
```